# What happens when HDInsight source data from Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Hadoop job running on HDInsight and source data from Azure DocumentDB. This job runs once a day and as new data comes in the DocumentDB everyday, my hadoop job filters out old records and only process the new ones (this is done by storing a time stamp somewhere). However, as the Hadoop job is running and if new records come in, I don't know what happens to them. Are they fed to running job or not?  How does the throttling mechanism in DocumentDB play roles here?

Answer (score 0):

1. *as the hadoop job is running and if new records come in, I don't know what happens to them. Are they fed to running job or not?*

The answer to this depends on what phase or step the hadoop job is in. Data gets pulled once at the beginning. Documents added while data is getting pulled will be included in the Hadoop job results. Documents added after data is finished getting pulled will not included in the Hadoop job results.

**Note:** ORDER BY _ts is needed for consistent behavior - as the Hadoop job simple follows the continuation token when paging through query results.

2. *"How the throttling mechanism in DocumentDB play roles here?"*

The DocumentDB Hadoop connector will automatically retry when throttled.

Comment: How should I use ORDER BY when sourcing data from documentdb?

Comment: Besides, when the last successful mapper starts processijg its first record, what is when all the records are read from documentdb?

Comment: Simply append the ORDER BY clause to the end of your DocumentDB query.

Comment: E.g. step 4.2 in the following document shows how to specify the input DoucmentDB query as part of a Hive Job:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-run-hadoop-with-hdinsight/#RunHive